# Puppet docker-modules does not work for Jenkins slave(node)

Tags: docker, jenkins, puppet, jenkins-pipeline, docker-swarm

thirst of all thanks for spending time reading this..
I am trying to achieve:

1. installing Puppet on all my instances (Master, agent1, agent2, etc) **DONE**
2. from puppet master installing  `puppetlabs/docker` now I got docker on all my instances.. **DONE**
3. I put all my instances in docker SWARM-manager MODE! **DONE**
4. on Master installing Jenkins `docker service create --name jenkins-master  -p 50000:50000 -p 80:8080 jenkins`  and in Jenkins installing self-organizing swarm plugin. **DONE**
5. creating docker secret for all instances `echo "-master  http://35.23...  -password admin -username admin" | docker secret create jenkins-v1 -` **DONE**
6. When trying to create a jenkins node..  **FAIL** nothing happens

   `docker service create \
   --mode=global \
   --name jenkins-swarm-agent \
   -e LABELS=docker-test \
   --mount 
   "type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock" \
   --mount "type=bind,source=/tmp/,target=/tmp/" \
   --secret source=jenkins-v1,target=jenkins \
   vipconsult/jenkins-swarm-agent`
7. I read before.. puppet module doesn't work with docker SWARM mode.. 
   Do you know any alternative ways to use.. Puppet>Docker>SWARM>Jenkins>slave-nodes/

please advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

```
echo "-master  http://35.23...  -password admin -username admin" | docker secret create jenkins-v1 -
```

pssd and user should be exactly like in jenkins user log in !